# retrieving data from NSDictionary with quotes already around the value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

How do i retrieve the value for key in a NSDictionary is the value already has quotes arround it

Code:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in jsonData)
{
NSString *firstName = [dict valueForKey:@"name_forenames"];
NSString *lastName = [dict valueForKey:@"name_surnames"];
NSLog (@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName);
}
```

in my dictionary which is :

```
(
{
"name_forenames" = Jordan;
"name_surnames" = Newton;
}, {
"name_forenames" = Jordan;
"name_surnames" = Newton;
}
)
```

because it just returns null in my NSLog

Comment: Data is coming from server or json is  defined in your project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary keys do not really contain quotation marks, that's only how the
`description` method of a dictionary shows strings that contain special characters.

So

```
NSString *firstName = [dict objectForKey:@"name_forenames"];
```

or the new syntax

```
NSString *firstName = dict[@"name_forenames"];
```

should just work.

Note that `objectForKey:` is the dedicated method to retrieve dictionary values.
`valueForKey:` is for Key-Value Coding trickery.

Comment: That worked THANK YOU !. For some reason the first method didn't work. the new syntax worked !

Answer (score 0):

You insert backslash in front of the quotation mark `\"`.

```
NSString *firstName = [dict valueForKey:@"\"name_forenames\""];
```